# WPF combobox with 3 object values and in template: Outputproblem

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, combobox, binding

**Selection now working, just the top displayd text in the Combobox is still wrong**

I had Problems with this and have made good headway with all the help i found on stackoverflow. but now i'm of a loss.

my objects are with in an Observable Collection and are definde as such:

```
public class PUNKT_TYP
{
    public int TYP { get; set; }
    public string TEXT { get; set; }
    public string IMG_SOURCE { get; set; }
}
```

and i red them in my xaml as such:

```
intd:IntdFilterableComboBox                                                     
                       IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
                       ItemsSource="{Binding PUNKT_TYPEN, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       SelectedValuePath="{Binding TYP}" 
                       SelectedIndex="{Binding PUNKT_TYP_Key_INT, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"                                                    >
        <intd:IntdFilterableComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding IMG_SOURCE}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TEXT}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </intd:IntdFilterableComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </intd:IntdFilterableComboBox>
```

Finally my Output variable is PUNKT_TYP_Key

```
public int Selected_PUNKT_Key_INT
            {
                get { return _Selected_PUNKT_Key_INT; }
                set
                {
                    _Selected_PUNKT_Key_INT = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Selected_PUNKT_Key_INT");
                }
            }
private int  _Selected_PUNKT_Key_INT;
```

for some reason the selected Combobox field (top of the combobox) doesnt display the TEXT of selected item but just my Object class : PUNKT_TYP

```
     -----------------------
```

I would be very thankfull for any help!

Comment: It's not clear how your selection is supposed to work. In case you want to select items by their `int TYP` property, your should set `SelectedValuePath="TYP"` and bind the ComboBox's `SelectedValue` (not `SelectedIndex`)  to a view model property of type `int`. Otherwise you may not use SelectedValue/SelectedValuePath at all and bind `SelectedItem="{Binding Selected_PUNKT_Key}`. The latter would require that the selected item is actually contained in the ItemsSource collection.

Comment: I changed the "SelectedValuePath="{Binding TYP}" " & the SelectedIndex="{Binding PUNKT_TYP_Key_INT}. My Output is now working but it still Displays the wrong text in the (Selection finished) Combobox field

Answer (score 0):

I found out why my displayed value was always (Namespace).(classname)
i needed to implement and override a ToString() function in my class

```
public class PUNKT_TYP
{
    public int TYP { get; set; }
    public string TEXT { get; set; }
    public string IMG_SOURCE { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TEXT;
    }
}
```